# Creating a new line when using .Replace

Tags: python

I would like to preface this with saying that I have combed the website and the tips i saw did not help my specific situation. Essentially, All I am trying to do is rewrite one string as another. One instance requires a new line to be generated before more data is added. All of the method I have tried have not worked. Any ideas? Thanks in advance. Here is what I have right now:

```
 if (Shape[z]) == 'Spherical':
                SpecPlat = SpecPlat.replace('[SHAPE]',(Shape[z]))
            elif (Shape[z]) == 'Conical':
                SpecPlat = SpecPlat.replace('[SHAPE]',(Shape[z]) + (" ") + (Min_Cone[z]) + (" ") +  (Max_Cone[z]))
            else:
                print("Invalid Sensor Input")
            out.write(SpecPlat)
```

I am trying to go to a new line in the Conical section right after the (Shape[z]) entry. Thanks

Comment: A side note; having brackets around pretty much everything in this code is not necessary and actually makes it a lot harder to read. `if Shape[z] == 'Spherical':` is perfectly fine, as is `+ " " +`

Answer (score 3):

Use `'\n'`:

```
SpecPlat = SpecPlat.replace('[SHAPE]',(Shape[z]) + ("\n") + (Min_Cone[z]) + ("\n") +  (Max_Cone[z]))
```